# execv(parent_process) when execv will be completed?

Tags: execv

In by program execv(parent_process) is called and parent_process does fork and exits .
when does execv() execution is completed. Will it be after child completion or immediately after  parent_process completion.

In my program i what it be exited immediately after  parent_process completion.

Comment: This is OS specific, or at least POSIX specific. Read documentation of [execv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) and of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) since you are misunderstanding how `fork` and `execve` work

Comment: As phrased, your question has no sense. `exec`... functions are executing *programs* not *processes*.